# The onmouseover and onmouseout events in php code doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to echo html code with php but 2 events of div tag do not work, onmouseover and onmouseout. I write code as below:

```
echo "<a href='#'>
    <div onmouseover='this.style.backgroundColor = #000000' onmouseout='this.style.backgroundColor = #fffffff' class='row' style='text-align:left'>
        <div class='col-lg-3'>
            <img class='img-responsive' src='".$usermsgavatar."'/>.           
        </div>
        <div class='col-lg-9'>
            <div class='row'>
                <div class=col-lg-5'>".$rows1[4].": </div>
                <div class='col-lg-7'></div>
            </div>
            <div class='row' style='text-align:left; border-bottom:solid thin;border-bottom-color:grey; margin-right:5%; margin-left:2%'>
                <div class='col-lg-1'></div>
                <div class='col-lg-11'>".$rows1[1]."</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
</br>";
```

I'm forced to echo this html code with php. I can't use any other ways.
How can I solve this?

Comment: those colors need to be strings in JavaScript. `...<div onmouseover='this.style.backgroundColor = \"#000000\"' onmouseout='this.style.backgroundColor = \"#fffffff\"'...`

Comment: `class=col-lg-5'` looks like a quotation mark is missing.

Comment: why don't you use CSS? `div.colorx{background-color: #ffffff;} div.colorx:hover{background-color:#000000;}`

Answer (score 1):

The javascript you have defined is incorrect as the color itself needs to be a string literal. See the following example for the correct use:

```
echo "<div onmouseover=\"this.style.backgroundColor = '#000000';\" onmouseout=\"this.style.backgroundColor = '#fffffff';\"></div>";
```